# SQL to return a single line in the join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

would someone know how to limit the result to a single line in the example below? I get two lines as **STOCK** value has two different results. Not sure how to add **MAX** or something similar so the result in the join would only get me a single line...

```
SELECT * FROM abtItemTbl abt
LEFT JOIN BT_PUBLISHED_WCID_LEVEL bt 
    ON abt.UDA_WCID = bt.PRODUCT_ID
    AND bt.DISPLAY_NAME IS NOT NULL
    AND bt.COUNT_OF_WCID_IMAGES IS NOT NULL
WHERE abt.ITEM_PARENT IS NULL
AND abt.UDA_WCID = '49x1794x116430'
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data as well as desired results.  Include the entire query *as text* in the question.

Comment: You either need to use a lateral join, by using `OUTER APPLY`, `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY`, or aggregation. Depending on the your data depends on if you can use aggregation or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to aggregate before joining:

```
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT bt.PRODUCT_ID, SUM(STOCK) as STOCK
 FROM BT_PUBLISHED_WCID_LEVEL bt 
 WHERE bt.DISPLAY_NAME IS NOT NULL AND
       bt.COUNT_OF_WCID_IMAGES IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY bt.PRODUCT_ID
) bt
ON abt.UDA_WCID = bt.PRODUCT_ID
```